# Masonry reload & reloadItems not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

The masonry (v3) code:

```
$(function msnry(){
var columns = 3,
setColumns = function() { columns = $( window ).width() > 640 ? 3 : $(window).width() >    320 ? 2 : 1; };
setColumns();
$(window).resize(setColumns);

    // layout Masonry again after all images have loaded
    var $container = $('#portfoliocontent').masonry();
    var msnry;
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
    msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth:  function( containerWidth ) { return containerWidth / columns;}
      });
});
```

My masonry container (aka my portfolio)

```
<div id="portfoliocontent" class="portfoliocontainer"></div>
```

My goal here is to hide all the divs with the class 'designshwr' which works, however the reload of masonry isn't working at all.

```
$('.engineeringiC').click(function(){
    if($('div.item').hasClass('designshwr')){
    $('div.item.designshwr').hide('fast');
    $('.portfoliocontainer').masonry('reloadItems');
```

}

Any suggestions? I've been scratching my head for the past week at different ways to get it to work, and I still haven't gotten any luck on it :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved the issue in it's entirety.

```
$(function msnry(){
var columns = 3,
setColumns = function() { columns = $( window ).width() > 640 ? 3 : $(window).width() >          320 ? 2 : 1; };
setColumns();
$(window).resize(setColumns);

// layout Masonry again after all images have loaded
var $container = $('#portfoliocontent').masonry();
var msnry;
$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
msnry = new Masonry( container, {
itemSelector : '.item',
columnWidth:  function( containerWidth ) { return containerWidth / columns;}
  });
});
```

var $container = $('#portfoliocontent')***.masonry();***

If anyone else encounters this problem it's probably because you applied the masonry initialization to your container variable. It's working great now :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem . May be my solution not efficient but whenever i have got optimum solution till now I have used this. You can try this hopefully it will helps to you as well.

```
$('.engineeringiC').click(function(){
    var $container = $('#portfoliocontent').masonry();
    if($('div.item').hasClass('designshwr')){
    $('div.item.designshwr').hide('fast');
    //$('.portfoliocontainer').masonry('reloadItems');
    setTimeout(function(){ $container.masonry() }, 400);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however that line you added is generating the same results I've been encountering by messing around with different ways of reloading it.

The best result I've gotten so far has been via this code:
    $('.engineeringiC').click(function(){
    if($('div.item').hasClass('designshwr')){
           $('div.item.designshwr').hide('fast').removeClass('item.designshwr');
  $('.portfoliocontainer div.item').masonry();
}

The only issue is the way they're laid out. http://drootech.com.s3-website-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/dtindex.html